# Can't find mkvirtualenv, but can execute it

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, virtualenv

I'm trying to run `mkvirtualenv` from a bash script, and I'm keep being told that it can't be found - yet it seems that my system can't make up it's mind about whether or not it can find it. Can anyone explain why I can execute it from the terminal, but not from a script?

```
jimbo@wavefront:~$ locate mkvirtualenv
jimbo@wavefront:~$ which mkvirtualenv
jimbo@wavefront:~$ mkvirtualenv --version
13.1.2
jimbo@wavefront:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `which` to check for binaries/etc. It isn't standardized, isn't always available and is an external binary itself (and so is more expensive than the better choices).

The better choices are `type` and `command`.

They are both built-ins, both standardized (at least at their most basic levels) and, because they are built-in, can see shell functions and aliases too.

Answer (score 4):

It's because it's a function attached to the shell. Run this to see it:

```sh
$ type mkvirtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks very much - tough choice on answer selection I'm afraid :(